# Do I need to enable the firewall on Virtual Network if I have enabled the firewall on the application gateway?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, firewall

I have set up a Virtual Network with an Application Gateway (which has both DDoS Protection and Firewall enabled). The Application Gateway forward the requests to a WebApp. There are no other components in the Virtual Network.

I also see that there is a Firewall on the Virtual Network as well. When I enable it, it asked that I need to create a subnet called AzureFirewallSubnet.

My question is, do I need to enable this firewall? does it make any difference to my scenario?

Thanks.

My scenario is similar to [image: diagram].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No firewall in Azure can block traffic to a webapp (unless you are using App Service Environment), you need to use web.config for that.

So no, you do not need Azure Firewall in this scenario.

Comment: For blocking direct access to the webapp, I have used something similar by going to webapp-->networking--ip restriction and created a rule to allow access to Application Gateway's Front-end IP. Now it works find when I hit the AG and I get unauthorized if I hit the web app directly. Also thanks for your reply.